# Latin academic positions

Tags: academia

I was wondering if there was a standard system, at some point in history, for academic positions in Latin.

What I mean is that today each country has a standard system that names each academic position, for example in England if you are the head of a university you will be called a "chancellor", regardless which university you head, as long as it is in England.

Different countries today use different words for different positions, some are derived from Latin, some are not. I was wondering if there ever was a standard of Latin-language academic position titles that have been used in the past at some point by several or more countries? Because I'd wager some countries had Latin titles but they were the only ones to use them.

Comment: Interesting question! I asked a while ago at [Latin.SE](http://latin.stackexchange.com/) whether one can [distinguish lecturers from readers in Latin](http://latin.stackexchange.com/q/1685/79). No answers so far.

Comment: Apparently, most of the dictionaries doesn’t make the difference… I’ve tried an answer there http://latin.stackexchange.com/q/1685/79

Answer (score 3):

Possible sources :

- Alan Cobban, [The Medieval Universities: Their Development and Organization](https://books.google.it/books?id=oz0OAAAAQAAJ) (1975)

and

- Alan Cobban, [English University Life In The Middle Ages](https://books.google.it/books?id=nIiNAgAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover) (1999).

More general : [History of Universities Series](https://global.oup.com/academic/content/series/h/history-of-universities-series-hou/?lang=en&cc=us) directed by [Mordechai Feingold](https://www.hss.caltech.edu/content/mordechai-feingold)

Comment: Thank you! Can you also recommend something similar about the classical antiquity and the renaissance (if Latin was still used then)?

Comment: @mathgenius - University ia a [medieval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medieval_university) "invention": thus, no "classical antiquity". In the European Renaissance, of course universities still used Latin.

Comment: While these links may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the links for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked pages change.

Comment: While this answer is helpful, as @RobertColumbia points out, it does not contain the essential content from the sources presented. Because the links are books, link-rot is not a major concern as one can still locate a print copy, but the answer should still include at least a few sentences addressing the question directly.